# Serverless Framework - unrecognized property 'params'

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am trying to create a scheduled lambda function using the Serverless framework and to send it different parameters from different events.

here is my serverless configuration:

```yaml
functions:
  profile:
    timeout: 10
    handler: profile.profile
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(1 minute)
          params:
            hello: world
```

The issue is that when I run `sls deploy`, I get the following error:

```
Serverless:   at 'functions.profile.events[0]': unrecognized property 'params'
```

This is basically copied from the documentation [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/openwhisk/events/schedule/#schedule/), so should work...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you're referencing is for Apache Open Whisk.

If you're using AWS, you'll need to use `input` as shown in the [aws documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule#enabling--disabling)

```
functions:
  aggregate:
    handler: statistics.handler
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(10 minutes)
          enabled: false
          input:
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
            stageParams:
              stage: dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that you referred to is for OpenWhisk https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/openwhisk/events/schedule/#schedule/.

Cloudwatch Events (now rebranded as EventBridge) is at https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/#enabling--disabling. Sample code for reference

```
functions:
  aggregate:
    handler: statistics.handler
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(10 minutes)
          enabled: false
          input:
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
            stageParams:
              stage: dev
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 12 * * ? *)
          enabled: false
          inputPath: '$.stageVariables'
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(2 hours)
          enabled: true
          inputTransformer:
            inputPathsMap:
              eventTime: '$.time'
            inputTemplate: '{"time": <eventTime>, "key1": "value1"}'
```

Official docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/scheduled-events.html

Comment: Thanks! seems correct but Aarons answer seems simpler, so I am going for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I could see one of my configuration something like below. There we use **parameters** instead of **param**.

```
functions:
  test_function:
    handler: handler.test_function
    memorySize: 512
    timeout: 60
    events:
      - http:
          path: get-hello
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              queryStrings:
                name: true
```